# how to create query with MarkLogic java API that gets json documents that don't have a specific jsonKey?

Tags: marklogic

I'm new to Marklogic and need to do a quick evalution of Marklogic in (4 day's).
I was wondering how I can execute a query, using the java API, that will get me all the json documents that DO NOT have a certain jsonKey?

I'm dazzeld at the moment by the query api and don't know what to use for this.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Regards

Jan van de Klok

Comment: MarkLogic is a pretty big platform to evaluate in four days. You'll probably end up more confused than informed.

Comment: Yep, that is the case already :-(

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to use JSON key-value queries as https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_56295 describes? Those appear to be positive queries only, equivalent to `cts:element-value-query` terms.

For a more complex query you'd probably use the structured query option, described in the next section of the same guide. You could construct it in XML using the `search:not-query` and `search:value-constraint-query` elements. Or use interfaces like http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.NotQuery.html to construct it in Java code.

Another option is to use a simple string query with a defined constraint option, something like `cat -mytag:dog`. But that means defining `mytag` as a custom constraint with `cts:not-query` and `cts:element-value-query`. I believe you'd have to write that in XQuery. In the long run there's only so much you can do in MarkLogic without using XQuery.

Comment: the NotQuery is no option because that specific json key can have any value if it is present. So I can't come up with a positive query that I can use in the NotQuery. That brings me to another problem i'm facing now: how can i test a jsonValue using an operator in a relative simple way? I looked through the entire API doc but could nod find something like  :  b.value(b.jsonKey("id"), Operator.GT, "123"). It looks to me that only equality comparisons are allowed, is that correct?

Comment: I wouldn't rule out `NotQuery`. If this were a cts:query you'd want something like `cts:not-query(cts:element-query(xs:QName('fubar'), cts:and-query(())))`. That looks complex but it's the most efficient way to test for the absence of a given element. It's definitely a structured query, not a key-value lookup. An inequality query would also be structured, a `range-query` with a `range-operator`. You might get some idea of the underlying cts:query API from https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/cts_query